# Setting one card per row Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get bootstrap to show 1 card per row on small screens, 2 cards per row on medium screens, and 3 cards per row on large screens.

I'm attempting to do this using `<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">` which is working for medium and large size screens, but for small size screens, it still shows 2, instead of 1 card per row.

I would also like to have the navbar move to the top on the smallest size screens and remain on the left side on all other sizes. I believe it is the same issue as with the cards.

Here is a link to my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPQWKd

Comment: Your code is working. Check again!

Comment: Really? Maybe the issue is with the chrome debugger? How did you confirm that it's working?

Comment: I have checked your codepen and tried resize in it

Comment: Oh, ok, great, I guess it was the chrome debugger

Answer (score 0):

For mobile phone you can try use **col-xs** class..

so instead

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
```

you can use

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
```

more documentation you can see here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: really ?
btw for the responsive sidebar you can try this https://www.codeply.com/go/Rgq96HykJ2/sidebar-that-changes-to-navbar

Answer (score 0):

in Bootstrap-4 , use class `col-{number}` for small devices

example : `col-12` : 12 column grid in small devices

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
           <div class="card mb-2" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549737328-8b9f3252b927?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="150">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>

       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
       <div class="card mb-2" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549805308-061c5e00ff9b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="150">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
       <div class="card mb-2" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549948558-1c6406684186?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="150">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
       
       </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but when I use the debugger in chrome and adjust the screen size, I still see 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.. i will add explanation if this is what you are looking for. thanks

https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/KEVazw?editors=1100`88`